# trigger.io: How to transition to a new screen?

Tags: trigger.io

Is there a specific API that needs to be used? Can I have anchor links going to an activity screen? For example in android, we start a new activity screen when you click on a button. How would I achieve this in trigger.io?

Answer (score 2):

No, there is not a specific API.  You just navigate to a new page or Url fragment.  Here is one way (single html page) using Trigger.io, backbone.js, and jQuery mobile -

https://github.com/dragthor/jquery-mobile-backbone-template